# Simple res.redirect() not working as expected?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building a login page using Nodejs Express in the server side and angularjs in the client side.
I'm checking if the username and the password is valid in the server side if so I'm trying to go to another page but the response.redirect is not working to me.

Any ideas would be appreciated-

```
app.post('/upload', function(req,res) {
  if((req.body.username == "Admin") && (req.body.pass == "Admin")){
    console.log("good!");
    res.redirect('/newgallery.html');
    res.end();
  }
  else{
    console.log("bad!");
   return res.redirect('/');
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can see it returns the page(in the Network), but I need to to go there (to show the requested page at the screen)

Comment: What do you mean Not working, Can you please add more description??

Comment: There's a good chance you need to handle this in Angular, not on the server.

Comment: That was great idea, it worked! Thank you so much :)